# "java.lang.ClassCastException" error when running a udf in Spark

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I've been trying to problem solve this issue for a few days now and have not gotten anywhere - would love some suggestions.

I'm running one scala object from within a project which includes a udf which broadcasts a scala set (`dict`). This is being run from the IntelliJ IDE and the project is built with Maven

Now, this udf works just fine when I run it within another object contained in the same project (using dummy data in a dataframe), but when I run the same code on real data in a dataframe, I get `java.lang.ClassCastException` errors.

The key udf code is:

```
// does an exact match check against a set (Bool)
def listCheckExact(words: Broadcast[scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]]) = {
  udf { (s: String) => words.value.contains(s) }
}

df.withColumn("new_col", when(listCheckExact(sparkSession.sparkContext.broadcast(dict))($"column"), 1).otherwise(0) )
```

I thought it might be a spark or scala version mismatch error, but have checked my pom file to make sure all the versions are correct and have re-downloaded them from the maven repository.

The thing that is really doing my head in is that this runs on dummy data, and not on the real data, using the exact SAME project setup (same pom file and dependencies, all uploaded to spark as a fat jar with dependencies). In the real data code there is additional code which grabs and munges the data (and works just fine), but it fails when it comes to this exact same udf - how can that be?

The full error stack is:

```
17/09/07 14:06:57 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 17.0 (TID 5369, 213.248.211.179, executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/09/07 14:06:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 17.0 (TID 5370, 213.248.211.179, executor 1, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5058 bytes)
17/09/07 14:06:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 17.0 (TID 5370) on 213.248.211.179, executor 1: java.lang.ClassCastException (cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD) [duplicate 1]
17/09/07 14:06:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 17.0 (TID 5371, 213.248.211.179, executor 1, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5058 bytes)
17/09/07 14:06:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 17.0 (TID 5371) on 213.248.211.179, executor 1: java.lang.ClassCastException (cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD) [duplicate 2]
17/09/07 14:06:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 17.0 (TID 5372, 213.248.211.179, executor 1, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5058 bytes)
17/09/07 14:06:57 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 17.0 (TID 5372) on 213.248.211.179, executor 1: java.lang.ClassCastException (cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD) [duplicate 3]
17/09/07 14:06:57 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
17/09/07 14:06:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 17.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/09/07 14:06:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 17
17/09/07 14:06:57 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 17 (show at getDwData.scala:704) failed in 0.111 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 17.0 (TID 5372, 213.248.211.179, executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
17/09/07 14:06:57 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: show at getDwData.scala:704, took 0.223107 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 17.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 17.0 (TID 5372, 213.248.211.179, executor 1): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2853)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2837)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2836)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2153)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:644)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:603)
    at uk.nominet.renewals_analysis.uk.nominet.renewals_analysis.getDwData$.getDwData(getDwData.scala:704)
    at uk.nominet.renewals_analysis.uk.nominet.renewals_analysis.getDwData$.main(getDwData.scala:863)
    at uk.nominet.renewals_analysis.uk.nominet.renewals_analysis.getDwData.main(getDwData.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2089)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1261)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2006)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1924)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It may be related with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19938

Comment: @CarlosVilchez - i;ve had a look at that. checked that jars are available in the executer's classpath. didn't help.